# Accessing properties by variable assignment or calling function?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was reading `accessing object properties as variable` section from Airbnb's style guide which says it is good accessing properties like below

```
var luke = {
  jedi: true,
  age: 28
};

function getProp(prop) {
  return luke[prop];
}

var isJedi = getProp('jedi');
```

So I define a generic function like bellow

```
function getProp(obj, prop) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
       return obj[prop];
   } else {
       var msg = prop + ' is not a property of the object' + 
                 'you are trying to access';
       throw Error(msg);
   }
}
```

and call as

```
var isJedi = getProp(luke, 'jedi');
```

What is the performance impact of calling a function to access object property vs just assigning it in a variable where needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the performance impact of calling a function to access object property vs just assigning it in a variable where needed?

In absolute terms, in theory it's huge, because you're doing all of that work calling a function, passing arguments, creating a new execution context, etc., etc.

And yet, [when I measured this](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html) because I was worried about the impact of using `forEach`, I found that function calls are **really really fast**, even on the slowest JavaScript engine I could find at the time (JScript in IE6). And modern engines are **much** faster than IE6's JScript.

My larger concern wouldn't be performance, but rather:

1. The affect on code readability and,
2. (For the specific `getProp` you've shown), the fact that you're disabling one of the key features of JavaScript: The prototype chain (by requiring the property to be an "own" property)

More on readability:

It's common to need to access a nested object hierarchy, such as:

```
var n = obj.foo.thingies.length;
```

Consider what that would look like with `getProp`:

```
var n = getProp(getProp(getProp(obj, "foo"), "thingies"), "length");
```

That's, frankly, nearly unreadable.

Barring a **really good solid reason** to do that, I would just use properties in the normal way.

Comment: Also, it is a mistake to call `obj.hasOwnProperty` on an unknown object because what if I do `getProp({ jedi: true, age: 28, hasOwnProperty: "cool" }, "jedi")`?

Comment: @melpomene: Meh, if people do that, they deserve what they get. **;-)** But yes, being *really* thorough, you'd use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, propName)` instead. Unless these weird people doing this have gone and replaced *that*, too!

Comment: You don't need any particular weirdness for that. JS often processes data from external sources, such as JSON from AJAX calls or inline object literals output by `<?php json_encode($data) ?>` or equivalent. On the other hand, if you're already sure what properties your object can or can't contain, what do you need to check `.hasOwnProperty` for?

Comment: @melpomene: I've never seen a JSON feed with a `hasOwnProperty` key in it, have you? Of course you haven't. It's a theoretical problem, not a real-world problem. :-)

Comment: I have because I've written one. :-)